# how to parse graph cool service in android

Tags: android, parsing, graphcool

I want to parse the graph Cool service in android. I am unable to parse the data.

here is the URL:

```
 https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cj8dyjr0144dk33b7pz
```

have to parse this service

```
 mutation {
    updateLocation(

   id:"cjck0maq9q7ovs54z",
  lat:"16.11",
  long:"81.11"
   ) {
 id,lat,long
}
}
```

Please, any one has idea about that.Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: The given data is not in json format please check and repost

Comment: this is a graph cool service not json @Avinash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer the complete document provided by [Apollo graphql](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/). it is a GraphQL compliant client that generates Java models from standard GraphQL queries.this link provides a sample application for native android.
[click here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use a tool to create classes that do the parsing: [apollo-codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen)

It was mentioned in the docs here: [frontend quick start](https://www.graph.cool/docs/quickstart/frontend/android/apollo-moong1eeji)

So very similar to how you work with AIDL in Android.